# angular Cannot find module

Tags: angular

I have the below setup structure:

[image]

my routes.ts file has the following route:

```
{ path: 'user', loadChildren: 'app/user/user.module#UserModule'}
```

Whenever I try to go to the user route i keep getting an error:

> Cannot find module 'app/user/user.module'.

I've tried changing the route to:

```
{ path: 'user', loadChildren: './app/user/user.module#UserModule'}
```

but that returns a similar error.  checking online i've seen suggestions to stop the dev server and run it again using ng serve, but again same error.

If I change it to this:

```
{ path: 'user', loadChildren: () => UserModule}
```

it works, curious why the original does not.  I'm going through a sample and it was fine in the earlier samples.

Comment: Did you export your `UserModule` and add it in your imports at `AppModule` ?

Comment: the string path syntax works fine as long as your imports, declarations and routes are static. If code contains conditionals, where some routes are added based on some condition, chunks will not be generated for those upon first compilation, see if there is some conditional routes?

Comment: @Nour No i did not, i tried it now but that caused another error:core.js:1448 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: undefined is not a function
I added the below to app.module:
import { UserModule } from './user/user.module';
and UserModule to the imports of AppModule

Comment: @fatemefazli there is no condition around the route, it just a straight import   { path: 'user', loadChildren: 'app/user/user.module#UserModule'}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this solution

and you can see [demo on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/how-to-hide-navigation-side-bar-in-login-page-in-angular-4-proj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

```
{path : "user",loadChildren: './user/user.module#UserModule'}
```

Comment: Yes, as mentioned in my original post that works, but i'm curious why the other one does not.

Answer (score 0):

i think your path is wrong, try this

```
{ path: 'user', loadChildren: './user/user.module#UserModule'}
```

Comment: Doing this caused the below error:
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: __webpack_require__.e is not a function